# Autopy Mouse Functionality

Tags: python-3.x, mouse, autopy

How to performed Right Click with Autopy.

In autopy we perform mouse left click by

```py
autopy.mouse.click()   #to perform left click
```

how to perform Right click with autopy or is there any other way to perform right click.

I tried following way but not working.

```py
autopy.mouse.click(Button = "RIGHT")
```

```py
autopy.mouse.click("RIGHT_BUTTON")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered with similar problem. and I just found something that might be a solution.

In Argument, you just have to put `autopy.mouse.Button.RIGHT`. for example if you want to make it right,

```
autopy.mouse.click(autopy.mouse.Button.RIGHT)
```

likewise for the left, `autopy.mouse.Button.LEFT`. I hope it useful.